# node start with nodemon

Tags: node.js, express, npm

Learning node with express, downloaded and currently studing a structure template, but forget how to start the nodemon so that any update is automatically applied. I was given the command from where I got the template but lost the locaion and after readying up on some of the commands of npm, node,... I could not come up with how2. Thx

Currnet command to run the app is:

```
npm start
```

```js
//package.json

{
  "name": "eautoshop",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "devstart": "nodemon ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.2.0",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "mysql": "^2.17.1",
    "pug": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.19.4"
  }
}
```

```
nodemon app
```

gives the error:

> 'nodemon' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Comment: if you want to use local dependencies, prepend the command with `npx` that adds `node_modules/.bin` folder to the path before executing the command.

Answer (score 1):

You can just point the nodemon executable...

```
node node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js bin/www
```